# How do I find the process running ICMP ping

Tags: network, ping

I can see from Wireshark that my Mac is sending ICMP request to 1.1.1.1, but I don't know where it originates from (I am not running ping in my terminal)

How can I identify the source?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17191/need-help-identifying-the-osx-process-thats-generating-strange-network-traffic